# Сделать метод копирования объекта

Tags: java

Нужно сделать метод копирования (не через сlone, а в ручную) объекта.

`obj1=obj2;` не подходит, так как оно  просто ссылочку перекинет и все (класс - ссылочный тип).

Нужно, чтобы 2 объект был независимым от второго, т.е. копирнул его  - и есть возможность менять его, не трогая первый объект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так можно:

```
public class MyObject {
      private int field1;
      private String field2;
      private List<String> field3 = new ArrayList<String>();

      // конструктор копий
      public MyClass(MyClass other) {
           // копировать все поля класса тут

           // примитивные типы передаются by value
           this.field1 = other.field1;
           // для остальных используем их конструкторы копий
           this.field2 = new String(other.field2);
           this.field3 = new ArrayList<String>(other.field3);
      }

      // метод копирующий объект
      public MyClass copy() {
           return new MyClass(this);
      }
}
```

Тут 2 способа, вызвать можно вот так:

```
MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
//...
MyObject obj2 = new MyObject(obj1);
// или так
MyObject obj2 = obj1.copy();
```

Вот почитайте, лучшие практики этого дела [тут](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).